# how to print stuff within tests on Plone

Tags: testing, integration-testing, plone

I'm writing some integration test with plone.app.testing.

Sometimes I want to print something to the console, but it seems to me that stuff gets printed on the console only when a particular test has finished.

Does plone.app.testing or some of the packages behind have some logging facility which I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support testing logging output, IOW tests that check that your code is logging things as it should, I think zope.testing intercepts all logging.  Additionally, depending on how you're testing, stdout may be replaced or intercepted, as with doctests for example, so printing to stdout may not work either.

Personally, I used [pdb.set_trace()](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace) or I force a failure temporarily, IOW without committing it, at the point I want to inspect and run the tests with ["-D" for pdb.post_mortem() debugging](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testing/3.9.6#debugging).

You may, however, be able to make some use of [zope.testing.loggingsupport](http://svn.zope.org/zope.testing/branches/3.9/src/zope/testing/loggingsupport.py?rev=116311&view=auto) to collect the information you want and then you can use a pdb.set_trace() or "-D" to get a pdb prompt at which you can inspect whatever handler you created to capture logging output.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this also: [Redirecting log output to sys.stdout on tests](http://hvelarde.blogspot.com/2011/03/redirecting-log-output-to-sysstdout-on.html).